# Visual Basic 2013 - Pressing ALT gets me out of code

Tags: keyboard, basic, alt

I just installed my Visual Basic and this is a problem I couldnt find an answer to. Everytime I press ALT it gets me out of code, and because I use SHIFT+ALT to change keyboards a lot while writing code, this is really disturbing to have to click in code again to be able to write.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Why did you tag this c++??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to the normal Windows way of accessing the menu via keyboard? This has nothing to do with Visual Studio; it will work similarly in almost any Windows application.
E.g. pressing Alt+F will open the File Menu etc. Just pressing Alt will highlight the menu (you should see the shortcut letters underlined for each item) and pressing a letter key will then open the menu. Instead, press Alt again to return to what you were doing before.

Comment: Darn, I didnt notice this, thanks. But Im also using Eclipse for example where it works just fine, doesnt highlight menu while im writing code and switching keyboards.

Comment: Yes. Eclipse is always a bit different... ;-) If I helped, could you please accept my answer? I need to collect Reputation...

Comment: Yeah sure, Im new here so Im still looking around and learning. Bytheway, is there a way to disable it? The menu highlighting.

Comment: Thanks. No, I don't think so. I never came across an application where you could disable this (and since I mostly rely on the keyboard instead of the mouse, I wouldn't want to); it's a standard UI mechanism. If you wrote your own application I suppose you could - and there _might_ be a way to hijack the Alt key using tools like AutoIt, but I don't really know anything about that. Also, in Visual Studio you can re-assign individual shortcuts like Alt+F to whatever you want, but that's not the general solution you're looking for...